# How do I solve this first order linear ordinary differential equation with factorization?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm getting an equation $$(\ln y - x)\frac{dy}{dx} - y\ln y = 0$$

Which I try to factorize and bring over to get:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y\ln y}{(\ln y - x)}$$

But this cannot be factorized further. I am intending to use either the the substitution $u=y/x$ or finding the integrating factor, but this form makes it hard for me to try either method. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Hint***

Substitute $y=e^z$
$$(\ln y - x)\frac{dy}{dx} - y\ln y = 0$$
$$(z - x)\frac{dy}{dz} \frac{dz}{dx}- e^zz = 0$$
$$(z - x)e^z z'- e^zz = 0$$
$$(z - x) z'-z = 0$$
$$z'=\frac z {z-x}$$
Then consider $\frac {dx}{dz}$ instead:
$$x'+\frac x z=1$$
Multiply by z $(z \ne 0)$
$$ x'z+x=z$$
Note the derivative of $xz$
$$(xz)'=z$$
Now integrate 
$$ x=\frac 1 z \int zdz$$
Evaluate the integral then substitute $z=\ln(y)$

Comment: Does that mean I need to use 2 substitutions to solve it? I am now getting $du/dx = \frac{e^u\cdot u}{u-x}$ but the $x$ is still inside the fraction.

Comment: I am getting a different answer for $z'$ as my expression is $(e^z \cdot z )/ (z-x)$

Comment: Found my mistake. But how do you integrate something like $x' + x/z =1$? The equation doesn't seem factorizable. How do you get to the next step.

Answer (score 1):

Hint...substitute $u=\ln y$ and you will arrive at a linear differential equation requiring an integrating factor.